# class file for javax.serverlet.GenericServlet not found

Tags: java, servlets, java-native-interface, hessian, javah

I have stuck in the class->header file for couple days!

I have tried on jni on Client by http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html and http://ringlord.com/jni-howto.html. And it succeeded in return "hello JNI C++" from JNI's (.cpp)file. Here are my steps:

1. create native function and in client.java
2. clean &build this client.java on Netbeans IDE, then result a client.class file
3. javah –jni [package].[classname]
4. create a dynamic library C++ project as first reference does, and put client.h into source file, and put some hello code into (.cpp)file ---> **It works!**

However, I tried to do the same thing on the servlet side and it's not working

1. Servlet.java->Servlet.class : ok!
2. Servlet.class->Servlet.h: fail!!!!
   **Error : cannot access javax.servlet.GenericServlet
   class file for javax.servlet.GenericServlet not found**

The following are solutions I have found and tried so far,

- check the package name
- sudo gedit /etc/profile,sudo gedit .bashrc, sudo /etc/environment; add JAVA_HOME & CLASSPATH on them, and source them to update, then echo $JAVA_HOME, echo $CLASSPATH to verify
- download servlet-api-6.0.14.jar & servlet-api-5.0.16.jar from http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.servlet.GenericServlet
  ,and add above two (.jar) by netbeans IDE->server->property->libraries->Add JAR

Please tell me how to figure it out this issue, thank you very much!!Btw, I am using hessianServlet

Comment: It is not a good idea to bundle your Servlet code in native class. Any specific reason to do so ?

Comment: I need to upload image to servlet, then use the c++ code in server side to do processing by openCV. So I need JNI native class on servlet in order to do <java call c++>

Comment: I guess that the class which declares native methods is deriving from javax.servlet.GenericServlet. Is there any reason why you need to do that?

Comment: Send the image from your Servlet to a simple java class method which calls a native method to do the processing. Compile the java class and generate the header file to use in your native code.

Comment: @Mohsin , so far I am only trying to return "hello world" from cpp to servlet. for the image path part, i have already uploaded image from client to server by heesian protocol;

Comment: @Pravel Zdenek , the reason why I use JNI on servlet is to provide other developers who feel more comforable in c/c++ coding with openCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeWrapper.java (you run `javah` only on this class)

```
class NativeWrapper {
  // either
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("MyOpenCVNative");
  }
  // or
  public NativeWrapper() {
    System.loadLibrary("MyOpenCVNative");
  }
  public native void callNative();
}
```

MyServlet.java

```
class MyServlet extends javax.servlet.GenericServlet {
  private NativeWrapper nativeWrapper = new NativeWrapper();

  public void someServletMethod() {
    nativeWrapper.callNative();
  }
}
```

Comment: com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianConnectionException: 500: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/example_ws_server/servlet/hwsexm

Comment: hi, @Pavel Zdenek, the above error message is what I got after following your tutorial.

Comment: Also, I have tried another method without using extra class like above NativeWrapper, then failed!                           private  native void nativeServletPrint();
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException{
   new ExampleServiceServlet().nativeServletPrint();
}                                                                      It runs ok return the processing result from servlet to client, but after i do javah on this servlet.class. no header file stopped my progress. thx

Comment: Don't mix your servlet class with the native methods. Keep it separated as posted in the answer. I can't help you with the IOException, i don't know Hessian. Post a new question, it's not directly related to JNI.